# Es posible usar un @Resource definido en la misma clase @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Tengo algo como esto:

La clase `Other` necesita una instancia de `MyBean` así que cree el atributo y lo uso cuando creo el bean `Other`

```
@Configuration 
public SomeClass {

     @Resource 
     private MyBean b;

     @Autowired
     Environment env;

     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         MyBean b = new MyBean();
         b.foo(env.getProperty("mb"); // NPE
         return b;
     }

     @Bean 
     public Other other() {
         Other o = new Other(o);
         return o;
     }
}
```

Pero me arroja `NullPointerException` al inicializar el objeto `myBean`, supongo que es porque la propiedad `env` aún no ha sido inyectada en ese punto.

Si no uso el bean sino llamo al método directamente todo funciona bien.

```
@Configuration 
public SomeClass {

     @Autowired
     Environment env;

     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         MyBean b = new MyBean();
         b.foo(env.getProperty("mb"); // NPE
         return b;
     }

     @Bean 
     public Other other() {
         Other o = new Other(myBean());
         return o;
     }
}
```

Es porque estoy definiendo el @Bean en la misma clase @Configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando tienes una clase decorada como `@Configuration`, Spring tomará los parámetros de los métodos como otros beans definidos en el contexto. En este caso, puedes enviar `MyBean myBean` como argumento y Spring inyectará el bean apropiado. En caso que tengas más de una definición para `MyBean`, es necesario colocar la anotación `@Qualifier` al argumento para especificar el nombre del bean que se quiere inyectar.

Para el código que presentas, esta sería la configuración a utilizar:

```
@Configuration 
public SomeClass {

     @Autowired
     Environment env;

     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         MyBean b = new MyBean();
         b.foo(env.getProperty("mb");
         return b;
     }

     @Bean
     public Other other(@Qualifier("myBean") MyBean myBean) {
         Other o = new Other(myBean);
         return o;
     }
}
```

Comment: Si, funciona perfecto, incluso si en `@Qualifier`  también funciona si uso `@Autowired`  en vez de `@Resource` pero tu opción es mejor toda vez que evita crear un atributo para la clase config que no va ahí

Comment: Puse el `@Qualifier` en caso que tengas más de una configuración para tu clase `MyBean`. Me ha pasado que han habido problemas por eso, por ello prefiero dejar el ejemplo con la prevención.